# How to get simple dispatch from this.props using connect w/ Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got a simple React component that I connect up (mapping a simple array/state over). To keep from referencing the context for store I'd like a way to get "dispatch" directly from props. I've seen others using this approach but don't have access to this for some reason :)

Here are the versions of each npm dependency I'm using currently

```
"react": "0.14.3",
"react-redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-router": "1.0.1",
"redux": "^3.0.4",
"redux-thunk": "^1.0.2"
```

Here is the component w/ connect method

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { people } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                <button onClick={() => { this.props.dispatch({type: ActionTypes.ADD_USER, id: 4}); }}>Add User</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { people: state.people };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    fetchUsers
})(Users);
```

If you need to see the reducer (nothing exciting but here it is)

```
const initialState = {
    people: []
};

export default function(state=initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === ActionTypes.ADD_USER) {
        let newPeople = state.people.concat([{id: action.id, name: 'wat'}]);
        return {people: newPeople};
    }
    return state;
};
```

If you need to see how my router is configured w/ redux

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
      thunk
)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

var Route = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      {Routes}
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

**update**

looks like if I omit my own dispatch in the connect (currently above I'm showing fetchUsers), I'd get dispatch free (just not sure if this is how a setup w/ async actions would work usually). Do people mix and match or is it all or nothing?

[mapDispatchToProps]

Answer (score 283, accepted):

By default `mapDispatchToProps` is just `dispatch => ({ dispatch })`.
So if you don't specify the second argument to `connect()`, you'll get `dispatch` injected as a prop in your component.

If you pass a custom function to `mapDispatchToProps`, you can do anything with the function.
A few examples:

```
// inject onClick
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onClick: () => dispatch(increment())
  };
}

// inject onClick *and* dispatch
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    onClick: () => dispatch(increment())
  };
}
```

To save you some typing Redux provides `bindActionCreators()` that lets you turn this:

```
// injects onPlusClick, onMinusClick
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onPlusClick: () => dispatch(increment()),
    onMinusClick: () => dispatch(decrement())
  };
}
```

into this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// injects onPlusClick, onMinusClick
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    onPlusClick: increment,
    onMinusClick: decrement
  }, dispatch);
}
```

or even shorter when prop names match action creator names:

```
// injects increment and decrement
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ increment, decrement }, dispatch);
}
```

If you'd like you can definitely add `dispatch` there by hand:

```
// injects increment, decrement, and dispatch itself
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators({ increment, decrement }), // es7 spread syntax
    dispatch
  };
}
```

There's no official advise on whether you should do this or not. `connect()` usually serves as the boundary between Redux-aware and Redux-unaware components. This is why we usually feel that it doesn't make sense to inject *both* bound action creators and `dispatch`. But if you feel like you need to do this, feel free to.

Finally, the pattern you are using right now is a shortcut that's even shorter than calling `bindActionCreators`. When all you do is return `bindActionCreators`, you can omit the call so instead of doing this:

```
// injects increment and decrement
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ increment, decrement }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

can be written as this

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { increment, decrement } // injects increment and decrement
)(App);
```

However you'll have to give up that nice short syntax whenever you want something more custom, like passing `dispatch` as well.

Comment: @DanAbramov btw is the second parameter in `bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)` optional? I noticed in your code at the `// es7 spread syntax` line, the `dispatch` is not passed to `bindActionCreators`

Comment: what is inside increment method ?

Comment: es7 spread syntax should be 

`function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators({ increment, decrement }),
    dispatch
  };
}`

Answer (score 7):

You can usually mix and match based on what you'd like.

You *can* pass `dispatch` on as a prop if that is what you want:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch) => ({
    ...bindActionCreators({fetchUsers}, dispatch), dispatch
}))(Users);
```

I'm not sure how `fetchUsers` is used (as an async function?), but you would usually use something like `bindActionCreators` to *auto-bind* dispatch and then you  would not have to worry about using `dispatch` directly in connected components.

Using `dispatch` directory sort of couples the *dumb*, stateless component with redux.  Which can make it less portable.

Comment: What you're suggesting won't work. You'll get an unbound `fetchUsers` injected as a prop. The shortcut notation only works when you pass an object as the second argument. When you pass a function you have to call `bindActionCreators` yourself: `dispatch => ({ ...bindActionCreators({ fetchUsers }, dispatch), dispatch })`.

Comment: Why spread and pass in dispatch directly in bindActionCreators? `dispatch =>  (
        bindActionCreators({
            dispatch, fetchUsers }, dispatch))`

Answer (score 2):

While you could pass `dispatch` down as part of `dispatchToProps`, I would recommend avoiding accessing the `store` or `dispatch` directly from within your components. It seems like you would be better served by passing in a bound action creator in connect's 2nd argument `dispatchToProps`

See an example I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455431/2644281 of how to pass down an "already bound action creator" this way your components don't need to directly know about or depend on the store/dispatch.

Sorry to be brief. I'll update w/ more info.